# How can I schedule an command with `at` which requires `Eth0` interface to up and running?

Tags: networking, email, mutt, at

Need here to schedule some email sending at some date with `at` command, but need first to ensure that Eth0 interface is up and running.

How could I do that?

Currently using Mutt Mail User Agent already configured.

Just adding the information that if Eth0 is down in the scheduled moment, it won't send the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to check if Eth0 (wired) connection is running:

`$ nano eth0ch.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
if grep -Fxq "up" /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate
        then echo "Eth0 Up"
        else echo
fi
exit 0
```

`$ sudo chown root:root eth0ch.sh`

`$ chmod +x eth0ch.sh`

Copy it into `/usr/bin`

`$ sudo cp eth0ch.sh /usr/bin/eth0ch`

Second to halt if it is down:

`$ nano eth0chk02.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

until [[ -n "$(eth0chk)" ]]; do
sleep 1
done
exit 0
```

`$ sudo chmod +x eth0chk02.sh`

`$ sudo chown root:root eth0chk02.sh`

Copy it into /usr/bin

`$ sudo cp eth0ch.sh /usr/bin/eth0chk02`

To start schedulling those emails sending, run it:

`$at Scheduletime`

Ex.

$at now + 30 days

```
at> eth0chk02
at> mutt -s "DestinyEmail@xxxx.com" < EmailBody
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Just adding the info that you can set the date and time in several different ways, as of:

`> at 10:15 18 aug 2023`, for an email to be sent at 10:15 of august 18 of 2023, or

`> now + 40 minutes`, to send it 40 minutes ahead of current time.

Comment: Why return a string and then test that, instead of just using the grep exit status directly (e.g. `until grep -Fxq "up" /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate; do ...`

Answer (score 3):

To see if interface is DOWN or UP:

> With GNU grep

```
ip link show | grep "eth0" | grep -oP "(?<=state )(\w+)"
```

Output:

```
DOWN
```

or

```
UP
```

or other state...

Comment: Just adding the fact that in Ubuntu wired interface is called `enp4s0` instead of `eth0`, as it is in Debian.